# csv to json to import into Freshdesk

Tags: python, json, csv

This might look similar to other questions on Stackoverflow but I can't find any answers which provide the json structure I need.

I want to be able to take a csv file, read through the data, convert it to json to be able to create new customers using Freshdesk's API.

To create a customer in Freshdesk, I need to convert the data into JSON. The format I require is:

```
 info = {
            'name': 'Test Customer',
            'custom_fields': {
                'company_reg_no' : '25865',
                'phone' : '0113 12345678',
                'date' : '2016-11-11',
                'address' : """Some Address,
                            Some Road,
                            Some Where,
                            SM1 1AA"""
            }
    }
```

I can open the CSV file:

```
csvfile = open('FDimport.csv', 'r')
fieldnames = ('name', 'company_reg_no', 'phone', 'date', 'address')
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
next(reader, None)
```

What I am struggling to do is to convert it to JSON, especially having to put some of the fields under the "custom_fields" key. I've tried to build a list or a dictionary and then call:

```
data=json.dumps(info)
```

But I can't get the correct structure.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT - Full code as requested incorporating Rob's answer

```
import csv
import json
import requests

FRESHDESK_ENDPOINT = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.freshdesk.com" 
FRESHDESK_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

dict_customers = []
with open('FDimport.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for csv_customer in reader:
        dict_customer = {
            'name':csv_customer['Name'],
            'custom_fields': {
                'company_reg_no': csv_customer['company_reg_no'],
                'phone': csv_customer['phone'],
                'date': csv_customer['date'],
                'address': csv_customer['address']
            }
        }
        dict_customers.append(dict_customer)
json_customers = json.dumps(dict_customers, indent=2)
print (json_customers)

r = requests.post(FRESHDESK_ENDPOINT + '/api/v2/companies',
        auth=(FRESHDESK_KEY, "X"),
        headers=headers,
       data=json_customers,
        allow_redirects=False)
```

Comment: Show us your existing code, please?

Comment: Can you show the not-quite-right json you are getting and comment on where `json.dumps()` is not meeting your needs?

Comment: Thanks Gents, I've posted the full code and the json I was obtaining before was all on the same level i.e. I couldn't put the custom fields under the custom_field node

Answer (score 1):

Lazy approach to creating the right JSON is to use the Invantive Query Tool, it performs the actions based upon common SQL and then just copy the actions:

- Execute an `insert into tickets(fields) values ('a', 'b'...)`.
- Copy the actual API actions performed in `select * from sessionios`.
- Optionally use `set log-http true` to spool text to files.

Answer (score 0):

Just construct the Python `list` or `dict` that you need, and pass it to `json.dumps`. Try this:

```
import csv
import json

dict_customers = []
with open('FDimport.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for csv_customer in reader:
        dict_customer = {
            'name':csv_customer['name'],
            'custom_fields': {
                'company_reg_no': csv_customer['company_reg_no'],
                'phone': csv_customer['phone'],
                'date': csv_customer['date'],
                'address': csv_customer['address']
            }
        }
        dict_customers.append(dict_customer)
json_customers = json.dumps(dict_customers, indent=2)
print (json_customers)
```

Depending upon how you invoke the REST call to freshdesk, you can use `dict_customers` or `json_customers` just as they are.

Test input:

```
"name","company_reg_no","phone","date","address"
"Test Customer","25865","0113 12345678","2016-11-11","Some Address,
Some Road,
Some Where,
SM1 1AA"
"Test Customer 2","42","666","yesterday","123 Main St,
USA"
```

Test result:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Test Customer", 
    "custom_fields": {
      "date": "2016-11-11", 
      "phone": "0113 12345678", 
      "company_reg_no": "25865", 
      "address": "Some Address,\nSome Road,\nSome Where,\nSM1 1AA"
    }
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Test Customer 2", 
    "custom_fields": {
      "date": "yesterday", 
      "phone": "666", 
      "company_reg_no": "42", 
      "address": "123 Main St,\nUSA"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! I get the structure but I get this error message when I try and pass it to Freshdesk's API:

Failed to create contact, errors are displayed below,
{u'message': u'Request body has invalid json format', u'code': u'invalid_json'}
x-request-id : b5dcd7c832b0605ba3198fdce15c5fa5
Status Code : 400

I'll have a look to see if there are any field errors

Comment: I've had a look at the JSON and it looks like it thinks it is a list as it is still wrapped with [ ] - is there anyway to remove the brackets?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of customers in the file by converting each list of data a `csv.reader` (rather than a `csv.DictReader`) gives for every row into a dictionary with the layout you need.

In the code below I use a `collections.namedtuple` because I think it leads to more readable code than using dictionary `dct['keyname']` syntax.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import csv
import json
try:
    from itertools import imap
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    imap = map

with open('FDimport.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    FIELD_NAMES = 'name', 'company_reg_no', 'phone', 'date', 'address'
    Customer = namedtuple('Customer', FIELD_NAMES)
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, FIELD_NAMES)
    info = [dict(name=customer.name,
                 custom_fields=dict(
                     company_reg_no=customer.company_reg_no,
                     phone=customer.phone,
                     date=customer.date,
                     address=customer.address))
            for customer in imap(Customer._make, reader)]

print(json.dumps(info, indent=4))
```